# FormulaArray concatinating and replacing error

Tags: excel, vba

tried to execute a big formula by joining multiple strings using FormulaArray to fill the result into a excel cell but unfortunately getting error at .FormulaArray 
When I try to execute part1 and part2 separately it working. But when I join them I am getting the Error.

```
part1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(SIP_Curve[[#All],[% of Payout]],MATCH(1,(SIP_Curve[[#All],[SIP_Component]]=""" & names.Item(i) & """)*(SIP_Curve[[#All],[Measurement]]=""" & measurementval.Item(i) & """)" & "str"

part2 = "*(SIP_Curve[[#All],[Performance Goal]]=RC[-6]),0),0),MAX(IF(SIP_Curve[[#All],[Performance Goal]]<RC[-6],IF(SIP_Curve[[#All],[SIP_Component]]=""" & names.Item(i) & """,(SIP_Curve[[#All],[% of Payout]]),0))))*RC[-3]"""

final = Replace(part1, "str", part2)
  With ActiveSheet.range("I22")
.FormulaArray = final
 End With
```

Comment: I'd add a `Debug.Print Final` before you attempt to write it to the sheet to see if you've closed all your parentheses and that you have the right number of double quotes in order for the formula to be correct.

Comment: You've misunderstood the purpose of the replace operation. You need to add a formula shorter than 255 characters as the `FormulaArray`, then use the `Range.Replace` method to alter it to the longer formula.

Comment: the Debug.Print is giving the correct formula by concatinating the multiple strings which is executing in excel if I copy and paste it with CTRL + SHIFT + Enter. But unfortunately FormulaArray is throwing Run time error 1004